# Importing jar file to android project

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to learn some android development. I created a small project and in my project I would like to import the twophase.jar (from http://kociemba.org/download.htm) to my android project so I can call the Search.solution method.

I can import the twophase.jar in eclipse and call the Search.solution method and get the return value as follows:

```
String result = Search.solution(testCube.toString(), 24, 1, true);
```

However, I am having a problem in Android. I can import and call the Search.solution method but I don't get a response. I am wondering if I am doing the import incorrectly or if there are any incompatibilities that is preventing the Search.solution to execute correctly.

I get the following in Android Studio after I call the method:

> I/art: Thread[3,tid=3318,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xa5344e00,peer=0x12c31e50,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
>
> I/art: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
>
> Application terminated.

I followed the import answer from Ganesh Pandey here: [Android Studio: Add jar as library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check what's in /data/anr/traces.txt . Can you share it?

Comment: I tried looking for the traces.txt file but I cant find it in my AndroidProject folder. Do you know where it will be?

Comment: The file is in Android device. Run following on command line `adb pull "/data/anr/traces.txt"`

Comment: Thanks Varad, I'll run that command when I get home

Comment: Hi Varad, I added the content of the file to my question

Comment: Can you paste entire logs from Android Studio here http://pastebin.com?

Comment: Hi Varad, I paste the entire logs here: http://pastebin.com/eYGwZRm3

Comment: Is this from traces.txt or Android Studio Logs?

Comment: @VaradChemburkar, i removed the jar file from my project. I think I should research the "Signal Catcher: reacting to signal 3" message. Thanks for your help!